# TFS 2017 Task Group/Library Updates not cascading?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I am not sure if this is a defect, or expected behavior, but I find when I update a TaskGroup or a Library in TFS, these changes do not always cascade down to each consumer.  The refresh to consumer does happen sometimes, but it's hit or miss at best.

If these Task Groups and Library features don't cascade down when you update them then what is the point?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "cascade". Can you provide a step-by-step example of the behavior that leads to the problem you're seeing?

Answer (score 0):

How did you use the `Task Group`/`Library` (`Variable Group`)?

Based on my test on TFS 2017 Update 3 (`Version 15.117.27414.0`), the `Task Group`/`Library` (`Variable Group`) works as expected.

That means once you have updated the `Task Group`/`Library` (`Variable Group`), then the corresponding changes and values will also reflect to the build/release which using the specific Task Group/Library.

For example, once I updated the value of the variables (Library-variable group), then the value also changed in **the next release**. Reference below screenshot.

More information please refer to [Variable groups for builds and releases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=vsts).

[image]

Comment: What I mean is the actual build definitions don't update.  They keep using the original value.  I open the build\release definition and the old value is still there, despite my having updated the task group or library.  Based on some experiments it looks like if your local value is changed in any way, even adding a space on the end, that build\release definition will not get the updated value.

Comment: @user5855178 I think you misunderstand the usage of the task group or library. In the build/release definition you have to link the variable groups to use the variables which created in the variable groups. If you mean you create variables under the variables tab in build definition and also create  the same variables in the Variable Group. Then in build definition it will only use the variables created in the definition but not use the variable groups. As in TFS 2017 the build definition cannot link variable groups, but in Release definition it works. And In TFS 2018 both working.

Comment: The build properties seem to be the most unstable.  We have dozens of build definitions here that all use the same Task Group.  IF I update the Task group properties, the corresponding build definition properties often remain the same.  Sometimes they do update, but sometimes not.

Comment: @user5855178 Based on my test Task Group works correctly on my side. All the updates will reflect on the build/release process. Please note that the Task Groups only work **within the specific Team Project**, it will not work in other team projects. I suggest you creating a new build/release definition and cleaning TFS and Browser caches, then check that again.

Comment: @user5855178 Have you resolved the issue? any update?